# Need help to understand an implementation of the Counting Sort sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, counting-sort

This code is about algorithms and datastructures. This code runs perfectly and i just have some questions on it because it seems like i don't understand two points. So my questions for that is:

1. which informations are in the countingArray?
2. how often is the while loop executed?

---

```
public class CountingSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] m1 = { 1, 17, 3, 1, 4, 9, 4, 4 };

        System.out.println("unsorted:");
        output(m1);
        int min1 = rangeMin(m1);
        int max1 = rangeMax(m1);

        countingSort(m1, min1, max1);
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        output(m1);

        int[] m2 = { -1, 13, 3, -1, -4, 9, -4, 4 };
        System.out.println("unsorted:");
        output(m2);
        int min2 = rangeMin(m2);
        int max2 = rangeMax(m2);

        countingSort(m2, min2, max2);
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        output(m2);
    }

    public static void output(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int rangeMin(int[] a) {
        int minimum = a[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] < minimum)
                minimum = a[i];
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    public static int rangeMax(int[] array) {
        int maximum = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > maximum)
                maximum = array[i];
        }
        return maximum;
    }

    public static void countingSort(int[] array, int rangeMin, int rangeMax) {
        int[] countingArray = new int[rangeMax - rangeMin + 1];
        for (int i : array) {
            countingArray[i - rangeMin]++;
        }
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = rangeMin; i <= rangeMax; i++) {
            while (countingArray[i - rangeMin] > 0) {

                array[c] = i;
                c++;
                countingArray[i - rangeMin]--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The array simply holds a count of how many times you have seen each element. For each possible element you make the while loop run through the count of that element. So the while loop runs as many times as the sum of all the counts, which is the same as the length of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountingSort` has `O(n)` time and space complexity. You iterate (i.e. use `for loop`) twice.

```
public class CountingSort {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        proceed(1, 17, 3, 1, 4, 9, 4, 4);
        System.out.println("---");
        proceed(-1, 13, 3, -1, -4, 9, -4, 4);
    }

    public static void proceed(int... arr) {
        System.out.print("unsorted: ");
        print(arr);

        countingSort(arr);

        System.out.print("sorted:   ");
        print(arr);
    }

    public static void print(int... arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr)
                                 .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%2d", i))
                                 .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
    }

    public static void countingSort(int... arr) {
        int min = Arrays.stream(arr).min().orElse(0);
        int max = Arrays.stream(arr).max().orElse(0);
        // contains amount of number in the unsorted array
        // count[0] - amount of min numbers
        // count[count.length - 1] - amount of max numbers
        int[] count = new int[max - min + 1];

        for (int i : arr)
            count[i - min]++;

        // fill source array with amount of numbers
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < count.length; i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < count[i]; k++, j++)
                arr[j] = min + i;
    }
}
```